# Delete the Current User Certificate for all Users

Tags: powershell, certificate

The code below is what I have been using to remove certificates from the current users store:

```
#Delete Certificates
$certs = Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My | where { $_.IssuerName.Name -like '*CN=Issuer*' }
foreach ($cert in $certs) {
    $store = Get-Item $cert.PSParentPath -Force
    $store.Open('ReadWrite')
    $store.Remove($cert)
    $store.Close()
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to modify this code to where it will delete this certificate on all of the user accounts on the machine. For example if I run it on User1 it will delete the certificate on User1 and User2. I have researched this, but have not been able to find anything on it regarding accessing other users certificate stores. Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something lightly taken on because a user's certificate store is saved in their registry hive. That means that in order to access a user's certificate store that isn't logged on you have to first load their registry hive, and then [manually decode their certificate blobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381955(v=vs.85).aspx) one by one to find the certificate that you're looking for. This is not recommended.

What may be a better solution is to set the script to run when each user logs in via a Group Policy or some such.

Comment: That is a good idea... I like it. Thanks for the recommendation!